# Clicking two separate buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click, element, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make an auto clicker with Javascipt. I'm trying to click two separate buttons in sequence. There should be 1 second between each click. When I run the following code, only one button can be clicked.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Buttons:

```
  <button class="btn-primary">Button 1</button>

  <button class="btn-secondary">Button 2</button>
```

Code:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary');
setInterval(function(){

for (var i=0;i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].click();
}
},1000)

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-secondary');
setInterval(function(){

for (var i=0;i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].click();
}
},1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use `var` and accidentally override the `elements` variable. Try never to use `var`.

I also changed the code to use modern syntax:

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('.btn-primary');
setInterval(() => {
  button1.click()
}, 1000)

const button2 = document.querySelector('.btn-secondary');
setInterval(() => {
  button2.click()
}, 1000)
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" onclick="console.log('1')">Button 1</button>

<button class="btn-secondary" onclick="console.log('2')">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet provided there are two problems:

- Usage of `var element` twice for different values
- The intended difference between both clicks is one second, but that code would leave the `click` events happen nearly simultaneously

Below is a modification of the code using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and functions.

`setTimeout` would call the other function after a difference of 1 second, so every click would be 1 second apart.

```js
function clickPrimaryBt() {
  var elementsPrimary = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary');
  elementsPrimary[0].click();
  console.log('click1')
  setTimeout(clickSecondaryBt, 1000);
}

function clickSecondaryBt() {
  var elementsSecondary = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-secondary');
  elementsSecondary[0].click();
  console.log('click2')
  setTimeout(clickPrimaryBt, 1000);
}

clickPrimaryBt();
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary">Button 1</button>

<button class="btn-secondary">Button 2</button>
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/vq8xb5oL/1/